# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'cannot decode special type '14' on pre iOS 11 Devices

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a crash with one of my screens, which is initiated using xib file. The crash logs are hectic and do not actually point out what could be the culprit. On iOS 11 and 12 everything works smoothly. I searched the web, as NSInternalInconsistencyException is quite common, but nothing came up with the same reason that I had.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'cannot decode special type '14''
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x04faa494 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x04772e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
2   CoreFoundation                      0x04faa3bd +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
3   Foundation                          0x01f62945 newDecodedValue + 497
4   Foundation                          0x01f65ce4 -[NSPlaceholderValue initWithCoder:] + 32
5   UIKit                               0x0379949d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 739
6   UIKit                               0x037991b2 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 320
7   UIKit                               0x034bb719 -[_UIAttributeTraitStorageRecord initWithCoder:] + 157
8   UIKit                               0x0379949d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 739
9   UIKit                               0x037996ae UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1268
10  UIKit                               0x037991b2 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 320
11  UIKit                               0x034ba383 -[_UITraitStorage initWithCoder:] + 227
12  UIKit                               0x0379949d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 739
13  UIKit                               0x037996ae UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1268
14  UIKit                               0x037991b2 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 320
15  UIKit                               0x034b9fdd -[_UITraitStorageList initWithCoder:] + 174
16  UIKit                               0x0379949d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 739
17  UIKit                               0x037996ae UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1268
18  UIKit                               0x037991b2 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 320
19  UIKit                               0x03585f21 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1627
20  UIKit                               0x03312380 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 429
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the use of language directional margins is not supported on pre iOS 11 devices. Replace it with standard margins in your Xib and the error with reason : "cannot decode special type '14'" should be resolved.